# Bash function not returning expected output

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a function for my Bash script to keep it DRY but for some reason the output of the code is not the same as when it's not inside a function.

What am I missing ?

Working:

```
#Get file name from file path
fileName="$(basename "$file")";
#Remove " ' and white space from name
fileName=${fileName//[\"\'\ ]/};
convert "$file" -resize $RESOLUTION\> "$OUTPUT_PATH"$fileName;
```

Not working:

```
function cleanUpName() {
  #Get file name from file path
  fileName="$(basename "$1")";
  #Remove " ' and white space from name
  echo ${fileName//[\"\'\ ]/};
}

convert "$file" -resize $RESOLUTION\> "$OUTPUT_PATH"$( cleanUpName $file);
```

Comment: you are not quoting the second `$file` reference. In fact, you are missing a lot of quotes, e.g. in the function's echo statement and around the `$(…)` subshell in the last line. This makes all these strings subject to multiple shell expansions.

Comment: Can you provide sample input that fail, expected output, and actual output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Robin479 suggested in the comments, I was missing quotes for my file variable working code is as follow:

```
function cleanUpName() {
  #Get file name from file path
  fileName="$(basename "$1")";
  #Remove " ' and white space from name
  echo "${fileName//[\"\'\ ]/}"
}
convert "$file" -resize $RESOLUTION\> "$OUTPUT_PATH$( cleanUpName "${file}")"
```

Comment: You should quote the echo argument and the subshell in the last line, i.e. `echo "${fileName//[\"\'\ ]/}"` and `"${OUTPUT_PATH}$( cleanUpName "${file}")"`